# Magento 2 dependency injection preferences in unit tests

Tags: phpunit, magento2

I was wondering why dependency injection preferences specified in di.xml are not being read by the `Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap` provided by Magento. 
I have found a workaround for it by providing a direct configuration setup for it:

```
Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->configure(
   [
     'preferences' =>
         [
           'Example\CoreInterface' => 'Example\Core'
         ]
   ]
);
```

Unfortunately it's not di.xml rewrite prone, so one day someone will rewrite the di.xml preference and break the tests. It would be nice to load the di.xml upon bootstrap of tests. Is there a better way of loading interface preference rewrites?